# Show the_author_meta user URL in a Post

Tags: php, iframe

I want to echo the_author_meta user URL in a post.
When I use a PHP snippet that contains the code below it won't return the URL but when I paste the same code directly into the single.php template, it does show the URL.
My question is; how can I show the_author_meta user URL in a Post?

```
<?php echo get_the_author_meta('user_url',$userID);?>
```

I would be grateful for a solution.
Best regards Peter